# How to generate text to speech from a live-updating, OpenAI data stream

Tags: node.js, text-to-speech, audio-streaming, server-sent-events, openai-api

This going to be pretty complicated so hopefully I can explain it right.

Im using the OpenAI Chat API to try and make a virtual assistant. What im doing, is submitting a query which is then run through the API, and the response is data streamed back to the client in chunks while it generates to reduce the apparent response time.

What i am now trying to do, is generate text to speech using the ElevenLabs voice API, as the OpenAI data stream is generating. I dont know if this is possible using ElevenLabs, or any TTS service for that manner, but if someone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

**Server-side**

```js
// Dependencies
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const { OpenAIExt } = require("openai-ext");
const voice = require('elevenlabs-node');
const fs = require('fs');

// Declare ejs, json formatting, set static files folder and initialise CORS.
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("json spaces", 2);
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(cors());

// Set the parser settings for JSON.
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

// OpenAI Config
const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: "",
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

// Set up Elevenlabs voice API
const apiKey = '';      // Your API key from Elevenlabs
const voiceID = 'pNInz6obpgDQGcFmaJgB';                 // The ID of the voice you want to get
const fileName = 'public/speech.mp3';                   // The name of your audio file

// Configure the stream (use type ServerStreamChatCompletionConfig for TypeScript users)
const streamConfig = {
    openai: openai,

    handler: {
        // Content contains the string draft, which may be partial. When isFinal is true, the completion is done.
        onContent(content, isFinal, stream) {
            console.log(content, "isFinal?", isFinal);
        },
        onDone(stream) {
          //  console.log("Done!");
            stream.destroy();
        },
        onError(error, stream) {    
            console.error(error);
        },
    },
};

// Set up SSE route for updates
app.get("/updates", (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    res.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
  
    // Send a comment to indicate that the connection was successful
    res.write(": connected\n\n");
  
    // Set up event listener for onContent updates
    streamConfig.handler.onContent = (content, isFinal, stream) => {
        try {
            const data = JSON.stringify({ content, isFinal });
      
            // Send the update to the client as an SSE event
            res.write(`event: update\ndata: ${data}\n\n`);

            if (isFinal == true) {
                voice.textToSpeech(apiKey, voiceID, fileName, content).then(res => {        // This is the closest I have been able to get,
                    console.log(res);                                                       // But this executes only once the content is done outputting
                });                                                                         // And still doesnt really work
            }


          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error sending update:", error);
            res.status(500).end();
          }
    };
    streamConfig.handler.onDone = (stream) => {
        // console.log("Done!");        
        stream.destroy();
        res.end();
    }
    streamConfig.handler.onError = (error, stream) => {    
        console.error("Big bad error: " + error);
    };

  // Handle any errors that might occur while setting up the stream
  streamConfig.handler.onError = (error) => {
    console.error("Error setting up stream:", error);
    res.status(500).end();
  };
  });

app.post("/openai", async (req, res) => {
    const messages = req.body.messages;

    // Make the call to stream the completion
    const response = await OpenAIExt.streamServerChatCompletion(
        {
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages: messages,
            max_tokens: 1024,
            temperature: 1,
            top_p: 1,
            frequency_penalty: 0.0,
            presence_penalty: 0.6,
        },
        streamConfig 
    );

     // Send a success message back to the client
    res.json({ message: "Request successful" });
});

// Check the login status of the user, then display the index.html file in the home page.
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index");
});

app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index copy");
});

server.listen(3000);
```

**Client Side**

```js
// script.js

// References
const queryBox = document.getElementById("query-box");
const mainContent = document.getElementById("main-content");

// Speech Recognition
const SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
let recognition;
let recording = false;
let speaking = false;

const skylaKeywords = ["Skylar", "Skyler", "scholar"];

const messages = [
    { role: "system", content: "You are a virtual assistant named Skyla that is designed to speak like J.A.R.V.I.S from the Iron Man Movies, and respond as such by including a bit of his sass in responses. You can refer to me as Sir if you so wish." },
    { role: "user", content: "Skyla can you speak more like Jarvis" },
    { role: "assistant", content: "Of course, Sir. Is there a specific phrase or tone you would like me to emulate? Just let me know and I'll do my best to channel my inner J.A.R.V.I.S for you." },
    { role: "user", content: "I want you to speak like Jarvis from the first Iron Man movie, incorporating just a bit more of his Sass in responses" },
];

let questionNumber = 0;

// Start Recognition on page load.
addEventListener("load", (e) => {
    speechToText();
});

queryBox.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter" && !e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("submit-query").click();
    }
});

function submitQuery() {
    fetchResponse(queryBox.value);
    queryBox.style.height = "55px";
    queryBox.value = "";
}

const source = new EventSource("/updates");

source.addEventListener("open", () => {
    console.log("Connection to updates endpoint opened");
});

source.addEventListener("update", (event) => {
    const { content, isFinal } = JSON.parse(event.data);
    const queryBox = document.getElementById(questionNumber);

    speaking = true;
    mainContent.scrollTop = mainContent.scrollHeight;

    // Update the element with the new content
    if (queryBox != null) {
        queryBox.innerHTML = "<img src='icons/skyla.png'><div><p>" + content + "</p></div>";
    }

    if (isFinal) {
        console.log("Completion finished");

        const audio = new Audio(audioFile);
        audio.play();

        messages.push({ role: "assistant", content: content });
        questionNumber += 1;
        speaking = false;
    }
});

// Convert speech to text
function speechToText() {
    try {
        // Initialise Speech Recognition
        recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
        recognition.lang = "en";
        recognition.interimResults = true;

        // Start Recognition
        recognition.start();
        recognition.onresult = (event) => {
            let speech = event.results[0][0].transcript;

            // Replace 'Skylar, Skyler or Scholar' with Skyla
            skylaKeywords.forEach((keyword) => {
                if (speech === keyword && !recording) {
                    speech = speech.replaceAll(keyword, "Skyla");
                    queryBox.classList.add("recording");
                    recording = true;
                }
            });

            console.log(speech);

            // Detect the final speech result.
            if (event.results[0].isFinal && recording && speaking == false) {
                let newSpeech = speech;

                skylaKeywords.forEach((keyword) => {
                    if (speech.includes(keyword)) {
                        newSpeech = speech.replaceAll(keyword, "Skyla");
                    }
                });

                fetchResponse(newSpeech);
            }
        };
        recognition.onspeechend = () => {
            speechToText();
        };
        recognition.onerror = (event) => {
            stopRecording();

            switch (event.error) {
                case "no-speech":
                  speechToText();
                  break;
                case "audio-capture":
                  alert("No microphone was found. Ensure that a microphone is installed.");
                  break;
                case "not-allowed":
                  alert("Permission to use microphone is blocked.");
                  break;
                case "aborted":
                    alert("Listening Stopped.");
                    break;
                default:
                    alert("Error occurred in recognition: " + event.error);
                    break;
            }
        };
    } catch (error) {
        recording = false;

        console.log(error);
    }
}

function fetchResponse(content) {
    // Append the speech to the main-content div.
    const newInputElement = document.createElement("div");
    newInputElement.classList = "user-input content-box";
    newInputElement.innerHTML = "<img src='icons/avatar.png'><div><p>" + content + "</p></div>";
    mainContent.append(newInputElement);
    mainContent.scrollTop = mainContent.scrollHeight;

    messages.push({ role: "user", content: content });

    // fetch to the api.
    fetch("/openai", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ messages: messages, }),
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {

            // Append the speech to the main-content div.
            const newResponseElement = document.createElement("div");
            newResponseElement.classList = "skyla-response content-box";
            newResponseElement.id = questionNumber;
            newResponseElement.innerHTML = "<img src='icons/skyla.png'><p>" + data.data + "</p>";
            mainContent.append(newResponseElement);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}

// Stop Voice Recognition
function stopRecording() {
    queryBox.classList.remove("recording");
    recording = false;
}
```

Comment: Have you gotten this figured out? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing, in my testing it looks like Elevenlabs is capable of doing it.

Comment: Hey @MiguelDey, no I didn't if you have it would be great if you could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

There might be Two Approaches -

1. May be you can call the 11labs API when u get a full stop(.) in the text response. This way you will be getting the audio for a sentence at least. And send back the audio as well as that text data to client when both are ready.
2. You can also call the 11labs from the client itself. This way you wont disturb the GPT response that you will keep on getting and along with that you will be calling 11labs from frontend when you receive a complete sentence.

Well in this approach you might not get the best audio effect but it should work.